# Determining changelist number for unshelve

Tags: perforce

I temporarily shelved my current changelist in order to work on something else.  When I went back to it, I had to scroll through hundreds of lines in my terminal to determine the changelist number.  Is there another way to get this number?

In Git, you can use `git stash` to save an arbitrary number of changesets.  when you `pop` a stash, you can specify which stash to pop.  Similar functionality is also available in Mercurial.  I use Mercurial Queues (`mq`) because I am familiar with them but there are a number of ways to do this in Mercurial.

Is similar functionality available in Perforce?  Are these changelist numbers stored anywhere or do I have to remember them?  I am using the command line (not P4V).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the 'p4 changes' command along with any of the flags for 'shelved' status and/or user.  See the examples below.

```
$ p4 changes -s shelved
Change 12118 on 2014/06/25 by admin@admin14streams *pending* 'original shelve changes by admi'
Change 12105 on 2011/11/08 by John_Wakeman@jw_admin *pending* 'Demo changes by John Wakeman '
Change 12102 on 2011/11/07 by Joe_Coder@jc_admin *pending* 'Joe_Coder_gwt-streams work '
Change 12101 on 2011/11/07 by John_Wakeman@jw_admin *pending* 'Demo changes by John Wakeman '
Change 12100 on 2011/11/07 by Joe_Coder@jc_admin *pending* 'Joe_Coder classic work in progr'
```

Here is using both the '-s' status flag and '-u' user flag

```
$ p4 changes -s shelved -u admin
Change 12118 on 2014/06/25 by admin@admin14streams *pending* 'original shelve changes by admi'
```

- 'p4 change' command reference
  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_changes.html